# Is there a way to calculate the CDF for non-normal data?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I'm aware on how to calculate the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of the Normal distribution. In R, e.g., one can calculate this given a normal distribution by using `pnorm(X)` , or given the non-standard normal using `pnorm(X, mean, sd)`.

But what if I need to calculate the CDF for a distribution that's not even close to a normal distribution? Is it even possible or as simple as using a built-in R function?

I've tried to search the web for some content on this question but I always end up in normal distribution related topics. Any suggestions on links regarding the subject would also be really helpful.

Comment: R has built-in functions for several distributions. For example, pt and pchisq among many others.

Comment: Run `help(package="stats")` and take a look at the "p" section.

Comment: Do you want to base the CDF on data?

Comment: If you look at different distributions on say Wikipedia, you can for many of them find explicit formulas for cdfs (and sometimes for the inverse-cdf). In other cases the cdf may be calculated using some numerical approximation (such as some form of series expansion, continued fraction, rational polynomial approximation or a number of other possibilities).  This [list of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) has links to nearly 200 such distribution pages. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... For example, consider the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) which has a nice closed-form cdf and quantile function, which is reasonably widely used. In R you can evaluate it by calling `pexp` (see `?pexp` for help). See the CRAN [Task View for probability distributions](https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2022-07-23/web/views/Distributions.html) for pointers to many such distribution-related functions in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a known distribution, R has built-in and need-to-install packages. You have to search for specific distributions like "Lindley distribution in R". There will be at least one R package for Lindley distribution. One example is [LindleyR Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LindleyR/LindleyR.pdf).
For a new distribution, you have got to develop by yourself.